# Product of 2 elements in $\ell^2$ is in $\ell^1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

If $a,b \in \ell^2 $ then $a\bar b \in \ell^1$

($\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$ on $\mathbb C$ and $\bar b$ is complex conjugate of $b$)

What did I write :

Since $a,b \in \ell^2 $, $a=(a_n)$ and $b=(b_n)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|^2 \lt \infty$  and  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|b_n|^2 \lt \infty$

But I cannot realize that how can I show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n\bar {b_n}| \lt \infty$ from above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: apply the [Cauchy-Schwartz inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: Thank you. Also I wonder how can I show it same thing  for Lebesgue spaces. Is Cauchy-Schwarz inequality still valid for integrals?

Comment: @user519955 [Yes it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality#L2)

Comment: thanks a lot :)